# Failed layout editor Android studio API 26

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Good morning people, has anyone ever faced the problems in the android studio layout editor using the API 26?
I already tried to go back to the API25, I did the gradle cache cleanup.

Below is the error and project settings:

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.9.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
```

ERROR:

```
 Rendering failed with a known bug. Please try a rebuild.  The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- com.github.gcacace.signaturepad.views.SignaturePad (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ViewBackgroundHelper   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatBackgroundHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatBackgroundHelper.java:46)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:63)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:56)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:95)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.NavigationBar.<init>(NavigationBar.java:52)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.NavigationBar.<init>(NavigationBar.java:46)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createNavBar(Layout.java:284)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:140) Copy stack to clipboard
```

Comment: The editor has been quite inconsistent with the 26.0.x build tools. I can't offer much to say but I've had those errors as well, particularly `AppCompatImageView`

Comment: I tried to return to API 25, cleaned the project, but nothing works.